# How to make sure that one android Activity resides in backstack only once

Tags: android, android-activity

Lets suppose activities(A,B,C) are opened in following sequence:

```
A -> B -> A -> C-> A
```

Now in normal case the activity backstack will look

```
| A |
| C |
| A |
| B |
| A |
```

Is there any way I can make sure that `Activity A` resides in the backstack only once? Or in other words backstack look like:

```
| A |
| C |
| B |
```

**EDIT** : I want that new instance of activity is launched every time, and all previous instances are removed from stack. Is it even possible using built in schemes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make use of the intent flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

Comment: Hi, thanks for help... But I want that new instance of activity is launched every time, and all previous instances are removed from stack?

Comment: Would re-initialising activity A's data and resetting its state in onResume() not achieve the same effect as launching a new activity A?

Comment: O goodness me.... How did I miss that. may be due extra work load.. Thanksssss a lottttt........

Answer (score 2):

You need to set  `android:launchMode="singleTask"` or  `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` for each activity in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

android:launchMode in your manifest may help:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

It's kind of geared to the main activity of your application though, not to arbitrary activities in your stack.

Edit: see NickT's answer, which i have upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want A to still be at the beginning then it sounds like you want to launch B and C as activities for results. See
[Activity.startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

That way, the original activity A will launch B and C and when B and C exit they will return to the original A.

Otherwise, If you want A to go to the top NickT has the right answer.